# Difference between gcc "-Xlinker" and "-Wl," options?

Tags: gcc, linker, gnu, ld, gnu-assembler

According to the [GCC 6.1 manual on Link Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options):

> **-Wl, option**
>
> ***Pass option as an option to the linker.*** If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.
>
> **-Xlinker option**
>
> ***Pass option as an option to the linker.*** You can use this to supply system-specific linker options that GCC does not recognize.

Why we need 2 of them?

### ADD 1

Similarly, why we need both `-Xassembler` and `-Wa` for assembler options?

Quote from [GCC 6.1 doc on Assembler Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/gcc/Assembler-Options.html#index-Wa-1113):

> **-Wa,option**
>
> ***Pass option as an option to the assembler.*** If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.
>
> **-Xassembler option**
>
> ***Pass option as an option to the assembler.*** You can use this to supply system-specific assembler options that GCC does not recognize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difference is into the following bold text

> **-Wl,option**
>
> Pass option as an option to the linker. If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas. **You can use this syntax to pass an argument to the option.** For example, -Wl,-Map,output.map passes -Map output.map to the linker. When using the GNU linker, you can also get the same effect with -Wl,-Map=output.map.
>
> **-Xlinker option**
>
> Pass option as an option to the linker. You can use this to supply system-specific linker options that GCC does not recognize.
>   **If you want to pass an option that takes a separate argument, you must use -Xlinker twice, once for the option and once for the argument. For example, to pass -assert definitions, you must write -Xlinker -assert -Xlinker definitions.** It does not work to write -Xlinker "-assert definitions", because this passes the entire string as a single argument, which is not what the linker expects.
>
> When using the GNU linker, it is usually more convenient to pass arguments to linker options using the option=value syntax than as separate arguments. For example, you can specify -Xlinker -Map=output.map rather than -Xlinker -Map -Xlinker output.map. Other linkers may not support this syntax for command-line options.

I guess 2 similar function still there due to back compatibility.

Comment: Thanks. It's not a perfectly reasonable world.